# Set Desktop Background to Solid Black with Powershell in Windows 11

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm adjusting settings on ~20 computers and I'd like to automatically configure the desktop to be solid black for all 20 displays using the PowerShell.  I have a script that I'm running to configure each of them, and so far I've found that the proper registry settings for setting the desktop to black are:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name WallPaper -Value ''
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers" -Name BackgroundType -Type DWORD -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Colors" -Name Background -Value "0 0 0"
```

And then I should reboot to restart Explorer with the updated registry keys.  However, this doesn't seem to work!  Is there another way I should be doing this? Is there a way I can make the registry keys take effect immediately so I don't need to reboot to see if WIndows Explorer took up the changes?

thanks!

Comment: Is the script running as the same user you want the modifications to apply to?

Comment: I think that was the issue!  I was running it as an admin; running it as a non-admin seems to resolve the issue.